# Ubuntu 14.04 can't find package dependencies

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I m trying to install some packages on ubuntu 14.04 server, and I m facing a problem.

When I try to run

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

I got an error that tells me that dependencies can't be reached.

```
build-essential : Dépend: libc6-dev mais ne sera pas installé ou
                            libc-dev
                   Dépend: gcc (>= 4:4.4.3) mais ne sera pas installé
                   Dépend: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) mais ne sera pas installé
                   Dépend: make
                   Dépend: dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5) mais ne sera pas installé


Does anybody knows how to make me able to run it ?
```

EDIT : I run as root

Comment: Try to run it with `sudo` command. For example: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: Sorry, I have root access, didn't precise it

Comment: You have messed up something in /etc/apt/sources.list: Ubuntu 14.04 for sure has gcc > 4.4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix any problem with dependencies:

`aptitude update; aptitude install -f`

`aptitude` is better for solving dependencies. Maybe you need to remove build-essential, install aptitude, and fix dependency problems. Then install needed packages (`build-essential`).

Answer (score -1):

---

> apt-get install build-essential

The right command is `# apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential`

---

Or you can install the same with `# apt-get update && apt-get install g++ autoconf`

---